# In APL how to turn a string into a one cell vector

Tags: arrays, nested, higher-order-functions, apl, dyalog

So, I have a function f that takes a string as input. I want to create a function g that maps f to a vector of strings. I.e.

`g 'Hello' 'world'`

should yield

`(f 'Hello')(f 'world')`

Here's what I did:

```
g ← {f¨⍵}
```

And this works just fine for the example above. However, it doesn't work when the right argument is just one string, as it maps f to every character of that string. For example:

`g 'Hello'`

yields

`(f 'H')(f 'e')(f 'l')(f 'l')(f 'o')`

Of course, I wanted the output to be `f 'Hello'`.

I could write

```
g ← {f¨⊂⍵}
```

So that `'Hello'` would be interpreted as

```
┌─────┐
│Hello│
└─────┘
```

But then `'Hello' 'world'` will be interpreted as

```
┌─────────────┐
│┌─────┬─────┐│
││Hello│world││
│└─────┴─────┘│
└─────────────┘
```

And then it won't map correctly.

Is there a way to solve this succinctly?

Comment: It'd be useful to know which APL implementation you use. If Dyalog, then you can use rak1507's solution below. If NARS2000 or GNU APL, then that won't work.

Comment: Let's say `f←{⌽⍵}`  then do you want `f 'Hello'` to give `'olleH'` or `⊂'olleH'`?

Comment: It's Dyalog APL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for ⊆

```
      ⊆'hello'
┌─────┐
│hello│
└─────┘
      ⊆'hello' 'world'
┌─────┬─────┐
│hello│world│
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, in future if you have other APL questions I'd recommend https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard

Comment: @rak1507 Or the easier-to-remember URL https://apl.chat